# This program is returning module os has no attributes for a Warrior Game

Tags: python, file, exception, command, txt

I'm having to code this program and essentially take warriors values like speed, strength etc and have it assimilated for equations and print commands later down. I keep coming back with the os has no attributes and I am stuck at how to code this so it works. Please help!

Warriors.txt contains:

```
45 
100 
3 
80 
150 
5
```

Imported Beg Stats contains:

```
#import mac os file

import os
import linecache

# game setup and open files

  
g = open('warriors.txt', 'r')

lines = g.readlines();

warrior_characters = []

warrior1_str = int(lines[3])
warrior1_ene = int(lines[4])
warrior1_spe = int(lines[5])
warrior1_dir = "right"

warrior2_str = int(lines[0])
warrior2_ene = int(lines[1])
warrior2_spe = int(lines[2])
warrior2_dir = "left"

g.close()
```

This is the code I am importing these files to:

```
field_warrior1 = 0

field_warrior2 = 15
field_warrior1 = int()
field_warrior2 = int()

time = int()
bothAlive = bool()
next_step = int()
index = int()

import os
os.system("warriors.txt")
exec(open("warriors.txt").read(), globals())

os.systems("imported_beg_stats.txt")
exec(open("imported_beg_stats.txt").read(), globals())

time = 0
bothAlive = True

   # display the starting game state
print ( " The Game BEGINS! Two warriors battle to the death to see who will be victorious... ")
print ()
print ()
print ()
print ( " TIME STARTS NOW : ", time)
print ( " WARRIOR ONE STATS : " )
print ( "  strength : ", warrior1_str, " energy : ", warrior1_ene, " speed : ", warrior1_spe, " direction of Warrior : ", warrior1_dir, " LOCATED AT BLOCK ", field_warrior1, " IN THE ARENA " )
print ( " WARRIOR TWO STATS : " )
print ( "  strength : ", warrior2_str, " energy : ", warrior2_ene, " speed : ", warrior2_spe, " direction of Warrior : ", warrior2_dir, " LOCATED AT BLOCK ", field_warrior2, " IN THE ARENA " )

print ()
```

Essentially the code needs to have two warriors fight, while the location and health are kept track of by equations further down in the code. It needs to run through the code but draw the warriors values from those files.

Comment: 1) Is there a file "os.py" in your cwd? (if there is, it will have priority over the built-in os module during import) 2) Please add the full error message to your question 3) Please reduce the code in your question to the **minimal** code necessary to reproduce the issue

Comment: As a side note, `exec(open("warriors.txt").read(), globals())` looks like a very bad idea. `exec` should not be used out of very specific - and rare - occasions. It's unsafe, makes the debugging difficult, and so on. If this is Python code, `import` what you need. If it is data, CSV or JSON, for example, are simple and easy to use.